# Getting the full name from a user

Tags: java

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String name = "John King IV. Cena";

    int start = name.indexOf(' ');
    int end = name.lastIndexOf(' ');

    String firstName = "";
    String middleName = "";
    String lastName = "";

    if (start >= 0) {
        firstName = name.substring(0, start);
        if (end > start)
            middleName = name.substring(start + 1, end);
        lastName = name.substring(end + 1, name.length());
    }

    System.out.println(firstName);
    System.out.println(middleName);
    System.out.println(lastName);
}
}
```

In above code I dont want middle name. I want to get full name from user then it has to split like firstname and lastname.

Comment: Why not splitting according to space(s)? `name.split("\\s+")`?

Comment: I'll give you a hand and edit your post for spelling and grammar. It will give you a much better chance of getting your question answered.

Comment: What do you mean you do not want `middle name` ? Could you please add the input for your program and expected output?

Comment: What about names like "Karl-Heinz" or dutch names like "van (der) Foobar"? There are quite a few names with spaces or - in it.

Comment: Are full name formats defined? otherwise you are going to fail splitting them.

Answer (score 2):

You can try String's`split` method to do this:

```
String name = "John King IV. Cena";          
String []nameArray=name.split("\\s+");

System.out.println("FirstName  "+nameArray[0] );
System.out.println("LastName  "+nameArray[nameArray.length-1]);
```

Comment: Robin van Persie is not amused. Other than that this solution does its job.